# Почему слайдер не подключается?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В общем подключил я jquery и слик слайдер начал писать файле js перед этим его подключив но слайдер не подключился подскажите если найдете ошибку буду благодарен

Весь код (не помещается тут по этому и ссылка на глитч)
https://glitch.com/~indigo-stone-sagittarius

Comment: А вы свой `script.js` подключите.

Comment: @alex071105  вы свой script.js не подключили на глитче, там только slick и jquery  http://prntscr.com/sydk1u вам на это указал InDevX